# Changing reported <file> in the traceback

Tags: python, module, traceback

there

I'm doing some custom module importing using the imp package on Python 2.7, namely creating a module from a string

```
exec myScript in module.__dict__
```

What bothers me is that all errors occuring afterwards in code in that module are reported as being from file  in the stacktrace.

Is there anything I can do to correct this and supply a name I want? What would the best approach be?

Comment: The best approach is as always - catch all exceptions and handle them properly.

Comment: @Lawrence sure, but I need the exceptions to be thrown, it's the way the system is designed to work.

Comment: Can you throw your own meaningful exceptions?

Comment: @Lawrence, yes, that is not a problem, as long as the traceback contains the correct error details (stack of function calls). I thought about catching all errors with some wrapping function and dealing with it. However, I still don't know how can I display the stack with a custom-specified <file> for some of the stack trace entries.